# problems with implementing Health Graph API authorization flow in PHP on WAMP server (localhost)

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0, wampserver

EDIT (7/8/16): The code below DOES work as it is. I tested it on my desktop PC. I want to leave the code because another developer may find it useful. The problem I have is unrelated -- I seem to be unable to do any HTTP POST with the WAMP server on my laptop, possibly due to firewall or some security software. I am going to look more into it today.

---

I am following the steps here, "Connect your Application to a User's Health Graph Account":
https://runkeeper.com/developer/healthgraph/getting-started

I am stuck at step #3 (Make a POST request to the Health Graph API token endpoint.)

After the code below, $response is blank and $httpResponseCode is 0. I think the CURL POST is well-formed, and I am not sure how to proceed.

This is my redirect page, where the user is directed after step #1, located at "http://localhost/my-site/redirect.php". I only removed the client_id and client_secret.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<?php

# RunKeeper API
define('client_id', xxxxxxx);
define('client_secret', xxxxxxx);
define('auth_url', 'https://runkeeper.com/apps/authorize');
define('access_token_url', 'https://runkeeper.com/apps/token');
define('redirect_uri','http://localhost/my-site/redirect.php');
define('api_base_url','https://api.runkeeper.com');

if ($_GET['code']) {

    $auth_code = $_GET['code'];

    $params = http_build_query(array(
        'grant_type'    =>  'authorization_code',
        'code'      =>  $auth_code,
        'client_id' =>  client_id,
        'client_secret' =>  client_secret,
        'redirect_uri'  =>  redirect_uri
    ));

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL     =>  access_token_url,
        CURLOPT_POST        =>  true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  =>  $params,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  =>  true
    );

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    $responseInfo = curl_getinfo($curl);
    $httpResponseCode = $responseInfo['http_code'];

    curl_close($curl);

    $decoderesponse = json_decode($response);
    $access_token = $decoderesponse->access_token;

    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure that the `php_openssl` extension is activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the $params array as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
You can use the below code for urlencoded.

```
$fields_string="";
    foreach($params as $key=>$value) 
    { 
         $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');
```

Then pass to $option array with value as

```
 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  =>   $fields_string,
```

Comment: This is not necessary. http_build_query uses that encoding by default. http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php